# How to set different context path for React app in NGINX

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, proxypass

I have deployed (using Kubernetes/helm charts) React app to http://localhost:30111/ using embedded NGINX. This single page application requires some NGINX rewrite rules for deep linking of static sources. There are following NGINX rules:

```
 server {
  server_name _;

  gzip on;
  gzip_static  on;

  location / {
    try_files $uri /index.html;
  }
}
```

Everything works fine and application is listening on http://localhost:30111/ as expected.

**What I need to do:**  I need to use new context path for this application e.g. http://localhost:30111/myapp instead of root context path http://localhost:30111/.

How should I write proxy_pass/rewrite rules in NGINX to work on new context path?

Comment: hi @ivan have you fixed it?

Answer (score 1):

Even though its late, i will provide my answer which may help someone later.

1. As a first step move all the files in the build folder to a sub directory which is same name of context path.

> build/myapp/...All static files will be placed here.

2. Add your context path in package.json file

> "homepage": "/myapp" -- this will help set process.env.PUBLIC_URL to /myapp

3. Add Basename in the BrowserRouter

```html
          <BrowserRouter basename={process.env.PUBLIC_URL}>
              <Suspense fallback={<Loader />}>
              // ... app routes...
              </Suspense>
            </BrowserRouter>
```

4. Change in your nginx configuration to use files from your sub directory

```js
     location / {
      return 301 /myapp;
    }
    location ~ ^/myapp {     
      
      try_files $uri /myapp/index.html;
```

5. You are done. Deploy your application and see Ui redirects directly to your context path and serving the files.

Comment: How can I implement context path in react js server-side-rendering path?